# Tablecolumn alignment

Tags: tables

Below is my latex code for my table. But the table is not aligning properly.  Also, I am getting an error "extra alignment tab has been changed to cr". Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
\begin{table*}[th]
\begin{scriptsize}
\caption{Experimental Results}
\vspace*{-2mm}

\begin{center}

\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{% 
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3.0}
%\scalebox{1}{
%\begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c||c|c|c||c|c|c|}\hline
\begin{tabular}{|M{4.5cm}||c|c|c|c||c|c|c||c|c|c|}\hline


\multirow{ 4}{*}{\Huge Benchmark} & \multicolumn{4}{|c||}{\Huge Original} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\Huge Trojan Avoidance (case1) } & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\Huge Trojan Detection (case 2)} \\ 
 \cline{2-13}

&  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\huge Area(PEs)} & \multirow{2}{*}{} &\multirow{ 2}{*}{ \huge \# contexts} & \huge Area(PEs) & \multirow{2}{*}{\huge  Energy Consumption} &\multirow{ 2}{*}{ \huge \# contexts} &\huge Area(PEs)& \multirow{2}{*}{\huge Energy Consumption} &  \multirow{ 2}{*}{\huge \# contexts}\\  \cline{2-3}  


& \multirow{2}{*}{\huge Maximum PE among }  & \Huge Total area &   &  &  & & & & & & & \\

 & \huge all the contexts(MX) & & \Huge  Energy Consumption& & & & & &  & & & &   
\hline
\Huge Ave8    &\Huge 10$(C_{19})$ &\Huge 107 & &\Huge 23 &\Huge 148 & &\Huge 64 &\Huge 192 & &\Huge  64 \\ \hline
\Huge FIR     &\Huge 15$(C_{40})$ &\Huge 236 & &\Huge 46 &254 & &64 &307 & &64   \\ \hline
\Huge Sobel   &\Huge 23$(C_{9})$  &\Huge 119 & &\Huge 17 &166 & &64 &211 & &64  \\ \hline
\Huge Bsort   &\Huge 30$(C_{5})$  &\Huge 105 & &\Huge 11 &158 & &64 &211 & & 64 \\  \hline
\Huge Kasumi  &\Huge 29$(C_{28})$ &\Huge 212 & &\Huge 33 &243 & &64 &288 & &64  \\  \hline
\Huge Interp. &\Huge 40$(C_{20})$ &\Huge 301 & &\Huge 28 &337 & &64 &382 & &64  \\  \hline
\hline
\Huge Avg. &180  & &26 & 218& &64 &265 & &64  \\  \hline

\end{tabular} }}
%\end{adjustbox}
\end{minipage}}
\end{center}
\label{table:results}
\end{scriptsize}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. How is the `M` column type defined?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. In this case a MWE would have caught the fact that there was something important missing in what you provided.

Comment: It's obvious that you have more columns in one of the rows than is allowed in by your `tabular` column specification. For example, the row containing `\huge all the contexts(MX)` has a total of 14 columns, yet you only allow 11.

Answer (score 1):

I've attempted to clean up your code in several ways. E.g., all explicit sizing instructions are gone, automatic line breaking is enabled (by using the `tabularx` environment and a centered version of the `X` column type), and instances of more than 11 column in a row have been eliminated. Given that the table has 11 columns, I suggest you render it in landscape mode rather than make it sufficiently tiny (and likely unreadable) to make it fit in portrait mode.

There's still more room for improvement. For instance, the header string "Maximum PE among all the contexts (MX)" seems unnecessarily wordy -- and it's certainly far longer than any other header string.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,rotating,ragged2e,caption}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\captionsetup{skip=0.5\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default value: 6pt

\caption{Experimental Results}
\label{table:results}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l||C|C|C|C||C|C|C||C|C|C|}
\hline
Benchmark
& \multicolumn{4}{>{\hsize=4\hsize}C||}{Original} 
& \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=3\hsize}C||}{Trojan Avoidance (case~1) } 
& \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=3\hsize}C|}{Trojan Detection (case~2)} \\ 
\cline{2-11}
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Area (PEs)} 
& Energy Consumption & \#~contexts 
& Area (PEs) & Energy Consumption & \#~contexts 
& Area (PEs) & Energy Consumption & \#~contexts\\  
\cline{2-3}  
& Maximum PE among all the contexts (MX) & Total area 
& & & & & & & & \\
\hline\hline
Ave8    &10$(C_{19})$ &107 & &23 &148 & &64 &192 & & 64 \\ \hline
FIR     &15$(C_{40})$ &236 & &46 &254 & &64 &307 & &64   \\ \hline
Sobel   &23$(C_{9})$  &119 & &17 &166 & &64 &211 & &64  \\ \hline
Bsort   &30$(C_{5})$  &105 & &11 &158 & &64 &211 & & 64 \\  \hline
Kasumi  &29$(C_{28})$ &212 & &33 &243 & &64 &288 & &64  \\  \hline
Interp. &40$(C_{20})$ &301 & &28 &337 & &64 &382 & &64  \\  \hline
\hline
Average &180  & &26 & 218& &64 &265 & &64 & \\  
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```